# Parsing directives in $sce trustedHtml

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/t9EA25uzYPwLjvO9FL2m?p=preview

Basicaly what I want to do is to be able to render an html partial containing directives inside a div with directives compiling on the fly. In my app I receive that partial from the back-end via Ajax (it's a sanitized html rendered from bb-code markup) and I'm using a filter instead of directly calling `$sce.trustAsHtml` inside the controller.

What have I tried so far:

My first attempt was to change the filter to use `$sce.parseAsHtml` instead. Like this:

```
app.filter('parseHtml', function($sce) { 
  return function(text) {
    $sce.parseAsHtml(text);
  };
}
```

This fails with an error saying `Token '<' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression`. So not working.

My second atempt was to use `$parse` instead of `$sce.parseAsHtml` but it failes the same way.

Is there any workaround or some simple directive|filter (actually I prefer a filter, but doesn't matter) I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Just as the previous post change your filter method to do this:

```
app.filter('parseHtml', function($sce) { 
  return function(text) {
    $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
}
```

And in your html do this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myHtml | parseHtml"></div>
```

Comment: That does not work. trustAsHtml` jut outputs the whole html partial withought compiling the directives inside.